# Displaying an array in a TextView in java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, settext

hi  i made a  program that counts the elements in an array and i done it already. Now i want to display the result in a textView.. I want to display it this way...
1 appeared 2times
2 appeared 1times
3 appeared 1times
6 appeared 1times

this is my code..
The last element only displays in the textView..
please help me..Thanks

```
 String []values = ( input.getText().toString().split(","));
 Arrays.sort(values);
 int c=1,i=0,range=4;
 while(i<values.length-1){
     while(values[i]==values[i+1]){
         c++; 
         i++;   
     }   
     jLabel7.setText(values[i] + " appeared " + c + " times");            
     c=1;
     i++;
     if(i==values.length-1)
         jLabel7.setText(values[i] + " appeared " + c + " times");
 }
```

Comment: append all the values into a single String object and then use the setText method to display the string...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

jLabel7.setText(jLabel7.getText() + "\n" + values[i] + " appeared " + c + " times");

Att:
If u are using swing componentes, is not a TextView but JLabel, or u are working for Android?

update your code to:

```
 String []values = ( input.getText().toString().split(","));
 Arrays.sort(values);
 int c=1,i=0,range=4;
 while(i<values.length-1){
     while(values[i]==values[i+1]){
         c++; 
         i++;   
     }   
     jLabel7.setText(jLabel7.getText() + "\n" + values[i] + " appeared " + c + " times");          
     c=1;
     i++;
     if(i==values.length-1)
         jLabel7.setText(jLabel7.getText() + "\n" + values[i] + " appeared " + c + " times");
 }
```

Comment: se my increment on the answer

Answer (score 0):

append all the values into a single String object and then use the setText method to display the string